# How to return part of javascript string that matches regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, strip

I have a regex string that matches the specific part of the string that I need as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/rJ8oC4/6).

```
/[^\/,\s\?#]+?\.[^\/,\s]+?(?=\/|\s|$|\?|#)/g
```

I want to use this regex in javascript to strip the parts of a string that do not match the regex and then store the result in a variable. I just cant seem to find any way of doing this!

The only regular expression functions I have found in JS are compile(), exec(), test() and toString(). None of these seem to fit my needs. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `string.match` ?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to remove the matched portion of the string from the original string **and** store that result in a variable?

Comment: that returns a boolean, I want to return the actual string

Comment: @KVohra95what's your expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `string.match` function to return all the matched characters as array elements.

```
string.match(/[^\/,\s\?#]+?\.[^\/,\s]+?(?=\/|\s|$|\?|#)/g)
```

If you want to remove the matched portion then use `string.replace`

```
var s = string.replace(/[^\/,\s\?#]+?\.[^\/,\s]+?(?=\/|\s|$|\?|#)/g, "")
```

Comment: for the record I didnt downvote, however this does not seem to be working for me. I am trying exactly this here -https://jsfiddle.net/gvkd0jfy/ but nothing is showing

Comment: sorry, got it working now...https://jsfiddle.net/gvkd0jfy/2/. I will accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this would be to use the `string.match()` function, as seen here on the [Mozilla Developer Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

So, your function call would look like

`string.match(/[^\/,\s\?#]+?\.[^\/,\s]+?(?=\/|\s|$|\?|#)/g)`

If you plan on stripping away anything that doesn't match, then you could use

`string.replace(/[^\/,\s\?#]+?\.[^\/,\s]+?(?=\/|\s|$|\?|#)/g, '')`, as seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and then store it into another variable.